# $\text{Prove that if} \sum_{i=1}^{m}|a_i - x|=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|b_i - x|$ Then $\text{ m=n and }a_j = b_j \text{for}0\le j\le n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

If $a_1\le a_2\le a_3 \le ......a_m \\ and \\ b_1\le b_2\le b_3 \le ........b_n$

$\text{Prove that if}  \sum_{i=1}^{m}|a_i - x|=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|b_i - x|$

Then $\text{ m=n and }a_j = b_j \text{for}0\le j\le n$

Here is how i tried , 
Assuming $ x \gt max\{ a_m,b_n \} $

I differentiated wrt to x:  $\sum_{i=1}^{m}|a_i - x|=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|b_i - x|\\
\Rightarrow m = n $ 
Similarly if i assume $ x \lt min\{ a_1,b_1 \} $ and differentiate the given eqn. wrt to x
$ \text{i get,  m=n }$

But i donot have any idea about how to proceed with this problem in general.
Thanks.

Ps: change the tags if incorrect.

Comment: Are $x$ and the $a_j$ and $b_j$ real numbers?

Comment: Yes they are real numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking derivatives is a good idea.
The function $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^m|a_i-x|$ is differentiable if and only if $x\notin\{a_1,\ldots,a_m\}$ and $f'(x)$ is the number of $i$ with $a_i<x$ minus the number of $i$ with $a_i>x$, i.e., at the points where $f'$ does not exist, it jumps by twice the number of indices $i$ with $a_i=x$. These are enough invariants to conclude the desired claim.

Comment: What about $a_j = b_j \text{for}0\le j\le n$

Answer (score 2):

You already proved $m=n$. Suppose $a_n<b_n$. Then for $x\in(a_n,b_n)$, one has
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n(x-a_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(x-b_i)+(b_n-x). $$
Differentiating both sides gives
$$ n=n-2 $$
which is impossible. So $a_n=b_n$. Repeating this, one uses induction to show $a_i=b_i$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$.

Comment: I get what you said.Under your assumptions ie, $a_n \lt b_n$, if $ x \lt min\{ a_1,b_1 \}$ or if $ x \gt max\{ a_m,b_n \} $ , we get n=n !!